00's movie with an infection where people become mindless drones
I have a vague recollection of this movie and would love to see it again, possibly from the early/mid 00s. Things I remember:

There is an instance where an 'infected' spits/throws up (eugh) into a water jug at some sort of conference or gathering to spread it.
The virus is to make society 'better' with no crime etc as everyone is so docile and mindless.
Once infected a person spends some time in a cocoon-type state of stasis once they sleep for the first time.
The main character is a woman, a mum, and her son is immune due to a (polio?) shot when he was very young.
The mum is infected but uses caffeine and adrenaline to stay awake so she doesn't turn into one of them, however there is a point in a drug store where she does fall asleep and her son has to inject adrenaline straight into her heart.
The mum has to get her son to a lab so they can use his blood for a vaccine.
They can tell when someone isn't infected as they move 'erratically', they perspire and they have short attention span, these people are incarcerated by the 'police' and infected.
There is a point where the mum is on a train with all the 'infected' but she lets some strands of cocoon grow on her so they know she's already 'infected' and don't pay her any attention.
POSSIBLY UNCONNECTED: the 'infected' kill off all dogs as they can tell when someone isn't right, and the mum found her neighbour's in the wheelie bin.

Any ideas?

Marked as a duplicate since The Invasion already came up here a couple of times in ID. Thanks for the detailed question, though.
